# Unity Realistic accelerometer controls

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, accelerometer

```
Vector3 acc = Vector3.Zero;
void update(){
    acc = Vector3.Lerp(acc, Input.acceleration, Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, (acc * -aVerticalRotation).x, transform.position.z);
}
```

I have the above code to move my GameObject vertically (along the y-axis). This works fine except that I want the object to move relative to my motion i.e.

If I tilt the phone some X amount very fast it will move distance Z whereas if I tilt the phone with amount X but slower the distance will be A where Z > A.

I've tried to get the current reading subtracting it from the previous reading and multiplying it with the rest but apart from causing a jittery effect it didn't work exactly as I wanted it to.

Can some one help me achieve this ? I'm quite new to Unity.

Thanks

Comment: I am doing something similar. At the moment I am just checking what the `Input.acceleration.z` is. If the device sits flat on a table, that value will be 1.0. Here is a good explanation of how the acceleration data works: 

http://www.instructables.com/id/Accelerometer-Gyro-Tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Your lerp code is incorrect.

Lerp returns a vector3 based on a start and end vector3 over time.  Input.acceleration is a Vector3 data type, yes, but it is not a world position.  It is the current values of the accelerometer.

You need to use the Input.acceleration values to create an end world position from your current transform.position (assuming this component is attached to the object you want controlled in the scene).  Then once you have that end point, set transform.position equal to the Lerp result.

Based on your game's axis and device orientation etc... the acceleration values may not map X to X, Y to Y, Z to Z.  You will need to play with it a little to get your end point calculating correctly.

For example, I use rigidbody physics, but my accelerometer Y controls my X translation:

```
rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(
                Input.acceleration.y * StrafingSpeed,
                0.0f,
                0.0f,
                ForceMode.VelocityChange
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code to do this. Perfect simulate the accelerometers.

```
rotFix = new Quaternion(Input.gyro.attitude.x, Input.gyro.attitude.y, -Input.gyro.attitude.z, -Input.gyro.attitude.w);
transform.localRotation = rotFix;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you take a look **[here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Input.html)**, this should be able to help you find out how to make the accelerometer give a numerical input that can be used to control speed. Hope this helps.